# How to Automate Adding Rows of Analysis for Excel Dashboard Feed Integration

Tags: commcare, microsoft-excel, integration

I am trying to integrate an Excel dashboard feed through the CommCare dashboard feed link. The dashboard already has multiple sheets and many formulas to process the data entry, which up until now has been entered manually. My goal is to have an automated system where the data will be updated automatically through the dashboard feed link, and for analysis of the data to be automated as well. However, I'm not sure if the analysis can be automated.

Specifically, the dashboard feed link would add a row of data to the Data Entry sheet of my dashboard for each survey filled. The analysis is done in other Excel sheets, and I would need rows in those sheets also to be automatically updated in order for the dashboard to be automatically updated also.

I realize this may be more of an Excel question, but is there a way to ensure that when a new row of data is added to the Data Entry sheet, corresponding rows of analysis (with built-in formulas) are added to the analysis sheets?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Excel guru, but I think this page on the CommCare Help Site goes through the steps to do at least some of what you're talking about: https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Tutorial%3A+Create+an+Excel+Dashboard. The key might be starting at "Step 4: Name your raw data for easy reference later" where is shows you how to mark all rows in the source sheet (including those not yet added) as source data.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, look for the "Fill down formulas in columns adjacent to data" option in those instructions. It will copy any formulas down when you add rows. I don't think it works across sheets though.